# Symbolizing OpenStreetMap layers in MapBox

Tags: openstreetmap, mapbox, tilemill

Newbie post here, so forgive me if there's a better place for this, or if my question has been answered already.

I am trying to develop an interactive trail map for my town. I have added all of the trails into the OSM database, with good topology and tags for technical difficulty, quality etc:

http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=16/49.0843/-117.7981

I am looking to develop the map using MapBox and Tilemill. My question is: If my main goal is to symbolize the OSM highway=cycleway features based on their difficulty tags, can I skip the whole tile creation process? If so, how would I go about symbolizing the various trails based on difficulty?

If I'm not interested in a custom basemap, is there any other advantage to using MBTiles? Here is my current working MapBox map, which is using a single MBTile:

http://www.kootenaymaps.ca/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/MapBoxEXAMPLE.html

Thanks in advance for any guidance here...

Barry

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with Tilemill but AFAIK it is designed to create webmabs on tile base only. So you might use **another desktop renderer** as [Maperitive](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Maperitive) for example. Please also keep in mind, that there are already various approaches to create hiking [maps online](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Maps), for [GPS](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_Map_On_Garmin/Download) and [printing](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_on_Paper) ;).